# How can I play the HTML5 games offline from a client side perspective?

Tags: html, web-applications, html5-appcache, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I am familiar with the use of manifest attribute for application caching. But I am trying to build a platform which will give the user to play an offline experience as well of the html5 games. Thus I don't have access to the actual code of the games. Do you think there could be a way for me?
Also tell me if I could use application caching from the secondary developers perspective.

Thanks!!